# How to prevent VS code formatter inserting spaces in vectors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-formatting

The Visual Studio 15 code formatter always inserts spaces in vector declarations

eg I get

```
vector< string > something;
```

instead of

```
vector<string> something;
```

Is there any way of preventing this?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, click on Tools -> Options.
In the left panel, select Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> Spacing.
You will see a tree of things in the right panel; one of the options will change the behavior you've described.